# Create an array to sort using keys

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

So I have a requirement where I need to sort products using their prices. In order to do this, I thought of the following logic in pseudo-code:

1. Loop the resultset of products
2. Add the price as the index of an array, and product ID as its value
3. Once all the products have been thus added to the array, sort it based on key

Now this works fine, when there are no two products with the same price. But since I have started having multiple products with same price, my code is breaking and only as product for same price is stored,sorted and displayed when using this method.

Can anyone give me some pointers on how to resolve this issue? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use something unique like the product ID as key

Comment: And then how do I sort them based on price?

Comment: Show us your current code and we will tell you.

Comment: Put your products in a database. Databases are great at sorting.

Comment: @Rizier123: In all fairness, I thought someone with enough rep points as you would better advice on an algorithm question than comment 'show us your code'

Comment: @Don'tPanic: The products come from third party API and we did not want to sent it through a DB just for the sake of sorting, which is why I am trying to have it done through some kind of array sort approach...

Comment: @UndefinedVariable Sure I could do. But I think it would be a bit pointless, if I would answer this generally and then you would have to modify my answer/code for your requirements. And to improve your code as much as I can I have to see it so that I can show you where you made mistake and what you can improve it

Comment: @Rizier123: Not to argue, but I think my question does fall under this guideline from SO ' We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers…
a specific programming problem, or a software algorithm...' And I have explained in my algorithm explanation where my shortcoming is, so I really don't think that you need to really see my code to show where I made my mistake. Because I already know where I made it. I am just trying to figure out how to work around that mistake. Anyhow, thanks for your time to comment on my question.

Comment: @UndefinedVariable I see, that makes more sense, then.

Comment: @Don'tPanic: Would it make sense to keep another array just for products which have same prices, and then sub-loop through those? I was hoping there might be a simpler solution than that...

Comment: This http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php didn't help? I think do as @Rizier123 said, keep ID as key, price as value and order by value, such as using [asort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

Comment: Everyone seems to agree on asort. :)

Comment: Yeah, I did not know about asort function before - this really helps! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rizier said it already:  You should **not** use the price for an array key.  You should use the product ID / SKU, or anything else unique to that product.

You can sort by price pretty easily then using [**asort**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) which will sort an array by it's values:

```
asort($array, SORT_NUMERIC);
```

asort will maintain the array keys unlike the standard sort function.

---

For the sake of people who find this question in the future and actually need to sort an array by the keys, you can use [**ksort()**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php) in the same way I used asort above.

Comment: aah, thank you - I didnt know about asort function before! :)

Comment: No problem, if this helped solve your problem, please mark it resolved.